# Can I renew my Canadian passport online while abroad?

Tags: passport, canadian-citizens, online-resources

According to [CIC News](https://www.cicnews.com/2023/05/canadians-will-soon-be-able-to-renew-their-passports-online-0535006.html):

> As of May 2023, the following groups will be eligible to take
> advantage of Canada’s upcoming online passport renewal system:
>
> - Those with expired passports issued in the last 15 years
> - Those with passports that were lost, stolen or damaged

However, I do not see any reference to the ability to renew Canadian passports online on the official sites:

- [Canadian passports and other travel documents: Applying in Canada](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/canadian-passports.html)
- [Canadian passports: Applying from abroad](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/canadian-passports-abroad.html)
- [Who can renew a passport](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/canadian-passports/renew-adult-passport/renew-who.html)
- [How to renew a passport outside Canada and the US](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/canadian-passports-abroad/renew-abroad.html)

Thus, I wonder:  Is it possible to renew a Canadian passport online?  In particular, can this be done while outside Canada?

Comment: The article was confusingly written. What is meant is that persons eligible for simplified renewal process would be eligible to use an online system in the future. And as of May 2023, the listed groups are eligible for the simplified procedure, and thus will be able to  use the *upcoming* online system, once it is put into place, if the eligible group does not change between May 2023 and the implementation of the online system.

Answer (score 2):

I received the following reply by e-mail from The Passport Program of Service Canada on Wednesday, Sept. 20, 2023:

> Thank you for your message of September 13, 2023.
>
> Sorry for the delay in responding.
>
> Please note that an online renewal application process is not yet available. However, it should be deployed soon.
>
> Depending on your travel plans, and to ensure your passport remains valid, you can submit your application for renewal at any time through existing channels.
>
> More information will be shared publicly about eligibility to renew a passport online.
>
> We hope we were able to assist you.